# symfony 2.1: phpunit -c app tries to run symfony core tests

Tags: symfony, phpunit

In my Symfony 2.1 app, I'm unable to run the [recommended](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#the-phpunit-testing-framework) `phpunit -c app/`. I get the following error message (I added linebreaks):

```
PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /symfony2-dual-auth/app/phpunit.xml.dist

F

PHP Fatal error:  main(): Failed opening required
'/symfony2-dual-auth/vendor/symfony/symfony/vendor/autoload.php'  
(include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
in /symfony2-dual-auth/vendor/symfony/symfony/autoload.php.dist on line 3
```

Complete source code here: https://github.com/meonkeys/symfony2-dual-auth . Except the test, since it doesn't pass. Here's `src/Oh/FOSFacebookUserBundle/Tests/SimpleFunctionalTest.php`...

```
<?php

namespace Oh\FOSFacebookUserBundle\Tests;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Tests\Functional\WebTestCase;

class SimpleFunctionTest extends WebTestCase {

  public function testIndex() {
    $client = static::createClient();

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/login');

    $this->assertEquals(1, $crawler->filter('html:contains("Remember me")')->count());
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you update from Symfony 2 to Symfony 2.1? Because in a clean Symfony 2.1 installation, the autoload.php.dist should try to include the Composer autoloader in the vendors directory. Try to reinstall your vendors using composer.

PHPUnit is not trying to run the Symfony core tests, but needs the autoloader to run your functional tests. This is why you don't need to require_once all dependencies in your test classes.

Comment: @Mark - no, I forked the Symfony 2.1 standard distribution. My code builds directly on the latest 2.1.x version. My test does not have any `require*` directives. The error is coming from a Symfony2 core test that is being run for some reason. I'll include the stacktrace. AHA... I was using the wrong WebTestCase.php file... I'll update my question and answer it myself.

Comment: Ah, good that you found the answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was extending the wong class. [Here's the fix](https://github.com/meonkeys/symfony2-dual-auth/commit/04d95341e8aa52b0e35b17cf2833b788ff00001e):

```
-use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Tests\Functional\WebTestCase;
+use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
```